# How to list all the keys inside a deep nested json using jq?

Tags: json, jq

Iam Parsing a very Large JSON which is multilevel nested.
So i want to find al the keys in the nested json.

What i did :

```
nsadmin@machine:~/$ jq 'keys' 474.json
[
  "x",
  "y",
  "t",
  "report"
]
```

What iam getting is the top level keys,but my report key has a value which is multi-level nested.So is there any way to print all keys inside this nested JSON using Jq.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a filter to get all the paths to all elements in the input and join them using `join`. You could also force the string conversion to avoid errors when joining numerals.

```
paths | map(tostring) | join(".")
```

`paths` outputs the paths to all the elements in its input (except it does not output the empty list, representing . itself).